# Avoid interface when working with generic-type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a messenger in my project that stores a collection of listeners implemented as follows:

```
Public Class Listener(Of T) : Implements IListener
  Public Property Recepient As Object Implements IListener.Recipient
  Public Property Action As Action(Of T)
  Public Property Channel As String Implements IListener.Channel
End Class

Public Interface IListener
  Property Recipient() As Object
  Property Channel() As String
End Interface
```

**The sole purpose of the interface is to allow me to cast and access the recipient in this non-generic method:**

```
Sub RemoveListener(ByVal listener As Object)
    For i = FListeners.Count To 1 Step -1 'step backwards to avoid ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        If (CType(FListeners(i), IListener).Recipient.Equals(listener)) Then
            FListeners.Remove(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a more elegant way to avoid having this interface (which I really only need for this purpose)?

Solutions/Suggestions in vb.net and c# are both welcome!

Comment: It looks like you know for a fact that the `listener` argument is going to be a `Listener(Of T)` object so why not declare the parameter as that type and declare the method generic too? `Sub RemoveListener(Of T)(ByVal listener As Listener(Of T))`. Then you don't need to care what `T` is within the method.

Comment: Hmmm... I think that I may have misread your code.  That suggestion won't work.

Comment: Is `listener` really a good name for that parameter, given that you're comparing it to the `Recipient` of each `IListener` object?  Wouldn't `recipient` be a better name?

Comment: The only options I can think of would be late binding, Reflection and an abstract base class, none of which is really much of an improvement.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney thanks for your ideas. I'm not 100% happy with the naming but that's an issue i'd not discuss in this question :)

Comment: You'ld have to re-think the entire implementation of your class, is not really clear to improve what aspect of it. Also, in this context an Interface, as it is, seems to establish quite a reasonable contract. A much more solid pattern than anything else that, at this moment, comes to mind. Ditching it to opt for reflection, doesn't look like a good choice, IMO.

Comment: Seems like an entirely appropriate use of an interface to me.  In fact, I'd almost certainly implement the same way.  The only thing that's potentially a little odd from a design point of view is the public `Action` on the generic (in the sense that it's not exposed through an interface, so it might be more appropriate to be `Friend` than `Public`).